# how to control digit number of displayed values above bar chart

Tags: plotly

I created a bar chart with value above the bar chart.

```
        fig.add_bar(
            # x=df.index,
            x=df['Wellname'],
            y=df.iloc[:,-1].values, 
            marker={"color": 'gray'},  
            name='Pad '+pad, 
            row=row,
            col=1,
            legendgroup = '1',
            text=df.iloc[:,-1].values,
            )
```

then, i used below to control number digit of displayed value above bar, for example, 2 digit number as below

```
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2f}', textposition='outside',row=1,col=1)
```

Now How can I make this number digit as a variable like this:

```
num_digit=function(key)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.%{num_digit}f}', textposition='outside',row=1,col=1)
```

The above didn't work. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Try this: `fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.'+ str(num_digit) + 'f}', textposition='outside')`

Comment: What if your text becomes `round(df.iloc[:,-1], 2)` ?

Comment: Thanks r-beginners, yes it works! Thank you so much! could you please make it a solution so I can vote? Thanks